# SCardGetStatusChange returns invalid result when a new reader is connected

Tags: smartcard, pcsc

I just detected strange evens after a new reader is plugged in. This is at the beginning of the initialization time (which takes less than 1 sec).

During this time the `GetStatusChange` function can return invalid events such as card present, although there is no card in the reader. At the end eventually the state will stabilize; no card event will be returned when there is no card.

Can I get rid of this situation in a smart way? The simple solution is to try to call `SCardStatus` function to verify if the event returned by `GetStatusChange` was correct and to hope that this function will return valid answer, but this solution is heavy.

I'm on Windows 7, but the same issue was also detected on Vista and previous operating systems.

Update: the only workaround that worked properly was using SCardListCards with conjunction of SCardGetStatusChange (SCardStatus requires Connect and it creates a real mess). By this workaround I just checked if events that are raised immediately after reader is plugged in are valid events. But this solution is heavy.

Comment: Please update the question with the reader/runtime used. Note that I don't see a direct answer. Already voted up, don't know what else to do.